# Repeating row numbers in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Trying to get a report to display a singluar intance of a row count, which I finally got working (Why is RowCount more complicated than it needs to be?) Which brings me to my next point, it displays the number of rows the amount of times that the row shows up!

[image]

Here's the formula that I am using:
[image]

SQL for this:

```
select distinct
    [File Number] = fm.FileNumber,
    [Client] = pc.Name, --Join FPR & PartnerType (PartnerTypeID = 1)
    [Abstractor] = pc1.Name, --PTID = 12
    p.State,
    [Title Order Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,fm.OpenedDate,1),
    [Title received date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,fm.OpenedDate,1),
    [Date Title search order placed] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,fa.SentDate,1), --ADID = 18
    [ETA to title order search received] = DateAdd(day,3,fa.SentDate),
    [Actual received date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,fa1.ReceivedDate,1),  --ADID = 19
    [Examination Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,fa2.SentDate,1),  --ADID = 654
    [Examiner] = IU.Firstname + ' ' + IU.LastName,  
    [Commitment Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,sd.CommitmentEffDate,1),
    [Final product to client] = CONVERT(VARCHAR,fa3.ReceivedDate,1)  --ADID = 799   
    ,pc.PartnerCompanyID as 'Client ID', pc1.PartnerCompanyID as 'Abstractor ID', InternalUserID
from FileMain fm
join FilePartnerRel fpr on fpr.FileID = fm.FileID AND fpr.PartnerTypeID = 1
join FilePartnerRel fpr1 on fpr1.FileID = fm.FileID AND fpr1.PartnerTypeID = 12
join PartnerCompany pc on pc.PartnerCompanyID = fpr.PartnerCompanyID
join PartnerCompany pc1 on pc1.PartnerCompanyID = fpr1.PartnerCompanyID
join FileActions fa on fa.FileID = fm.FileID and fa.ActionDefID = 18
left join FileActions fa1 on fa1.FileID = fm.FileID and fa1.ActionDefID = 19
left join FileActions fa2 on fa2.FileID = fm.FileID and fa2.ActionDefID = 654
left join FileActions fa3 on fa3.FileID = fm.FileID and fa3.ActionDefID = 799
join SearchData sd on sd.FileID = fm.FileID
left join InternalUser iu on iu.InternalUserID = fa2.SentUserID
join property p on p.FileID = fm.FileID
Where
fm.OpenedDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

What I am trying to do is get the "total" to only report 1 instance of the counted rows, see below:
[image]

Comment: Looking at your final screenshot, with the Total column: what would you like to see there? Only one row for the group where there are five?

Comment: That's exactly it, @JamieF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a group, or if the group already exists in your table, then you need to add the column to your group, not to the details group.

Try right clicking on the column containing the field that is being used for the group, and choosing "Insert Column -> "Inside Group - Right" Place your `countrows()` expression in the resulting cell.

The different ways of grouping and including columns or rows in or out of different groups will be key to building slightly more complex reports. If you are going to be using SSRS much, it's worth learning these. Google `SSRS Groups` for many links and tutorials, such as this [Technet reference.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220467.aspx)

Comment: So, this worked lovely, but the box now expands for each count like it's counting secretly, even if it only displays once.  And this is with CanGrow Off

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish but are you able to use SQL to get the count you need? (i.e. return a "Record Count" column from your SQL statement and use it in your report)

Comment: I am able to use SQL, but not sure of the syntax for that.

Comment: Without seeing your data and/or your current SQL statement, i don't think you're going to get much more help. Not to mention a better explaination of what your trying to do.

Comment: If you only have two columns in your total summary rpt, then you should be able to use SSRS to group. =Sum(RowCount("Client")) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712(v=sql.100).aspx